# Move all libs version to root gradle file in multi module gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have gradle project with modules.

```
-RootProject
 -my-server(spring boot 2server)
 -my-generator(module)
```

Now my root project's gradle file look like this:

```
    group = 'com.mayprojekt'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Gradle settings file look like this:

```
    rootProject.name = 'root-project'
    include 'my-generator'
    include 'my-server'
```

my-server's gradle file look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
        cxfVersion = '3.2.2'
        uuidGeneratorVersion = '3.1.5'
        commonLang3Version = '3.7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.mayprojekt'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.mayprojekt.Application'
    archiveName = 'my-server.jar'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws:${cxfVersion}"
    compile "com.fasterxml.uuid:java-uuid-generator:${uuidGeneratorVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-logging:${cxfVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonLang3Version}"
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3")
    compile project(':my-generator')

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

my-generator module just module with some classes.

But I want move all libraries versions to root gradle file. I make it in maven project and I need something look like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring.ws.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.version>0.13.2</jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.version>
    <cxf.version>3.2.4</cxf.version>
    <commons.codec.version>1.11</commons.codec.version>
    <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
    <oracle.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

But I don know how can I make this with gradle.

Comment: so you want to migrate the maven my-generator module to gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your my-generator project is a gradle project, then you can do this in the root build.gradle:

```
...

project(':my-server') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    ....
}

project(':my-generator') {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

...
```

Using the 'project' clause, you can apply configurations only to children module projects from the root project.

using the 'allprojects' clause you can apply certain configurations to all your child module projects:

```
allprojects {
    dependencies { ... }
}
```

Check this out https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-multi-project-build/

Hope this helps